# This pull request cannot be merged. You will need to resolve conflicts to be able to merge

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict-resolution, bitbucket-server

We are using Atlassian products to manage code. JIRA, Bitbucket, etc along with that we are using SourceTree for GIT. Here is the structure of GIT we are using:

Master --> Base1 ----> this contains production code.

Base2 --> A copy of Base1 also derived from Base1 ----> Contains Staging code.

every developer creates branch from Base2 commit code back to branch and then we merge the code back to Base2 and if it get passed then we move it to production code.

Sometimes it happens when a developer commits the code and then make a pull request in bitbucket, it does not merge and says "This pull request cannot be merged. You will need to resolve conflicts to be able to merge."  and when you see the diff tab it shows number of conflicts to resolve. But sometimes it gives the same error on pull request "This pull request cannot be merged. You will need to resolve conflicts to be able to merge." but does not show any conflicts in diff tab, can any one help to explain how to find the conflicts in this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the the "Atlassian product" name is "Stash", or now known as "Bitbucket Server"? I suggest adding tag "atlassian-stash" to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Stash (you mean it, don't you?) treats all failures during merge as "merge conflicts", and Atlassian is quite determined to not print the error messages from merge to UI, instead trying to show the conflicted files to Diff. You can try to contact their support. Otherwise just merge locally and push the merge.

PS: if your server uses Windows, it might be the path length issue which causes the failure.